# What is the optimal solution when there is incompatibility between Chromedriver & Google Chrome?

Tags: c#, chromedriver

Error: `System.InvalidOperationException : session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 85 (SessionNotCreated)`

I am using Google Chrome Version 87.0.4280.66 (Official Build) (64-bit)

[image]

From research, the options are:

1. Downgrade version of Chrome browser, so that it becomes compatible with the Chromedriver on my PC.
2. Update the version of Chromedriver in my framework to become compatible with that of the Google Chrome browser I currently run.

Comment: What do you mean by "Optimal Solution"? What variables would you take into consideration?

Comment: Why do test with chrome ?

Comment: @PDHide because my users use Chrome? :) What is the alternative and is there a browser that auto updates its driver? I think even Firefox removed the driver from the release.

Comment: @NielsvanReijmersdal Just wanted to ask whether the author is clear about that , it sounded like the expectation was just to get green reports and not to provide a early build feedback

Comment: @PDHide But the problem is is similar with other modern browsers not? They auto update. Which is a good thing I think :)

Comment: Most organizations disables auto update so there will be users who still uses old one so if the product is only focused at those minority group who makes the majority of customer base then downgrade browser . If majority of customers have auto update feature and the update is pushed globally then update browser

Comment: @JoãoFarias - Thanks for your response. I meant given both options which is better; considering the risks versus advantages - based on experience.

Comment: @PDHide - Thanks.. It's one of the browsers I am using for this test. I will be using other browsers too..

Comment: @OA345 there is no better option if you decide to update browser then you should replace driver , else  downgrade browser browser if you didnt wanted it to be updated. But chrome doesn't allow downgrading you have to reinstall old chrome user if you had saved it locally or from archive websites

Comment: @NielsvanReijmersdal.. Thank you.. I want to use the test resuls to get early feedback about my test as well..

Comment: @PDHide... I will take note of this; as well as your other, rather insightful points. Once again, many thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 3**: Use something like the WebDriverManager which auto updates the used driver to the latest version. For c# have a look here: https://www.qafox.com/selenium-c-sharp-webdrivermanager-configuration/

**Option 4**: The fourth option is to disable the auto updating of the chrome browser. See https://www.chromium.org/administrators/turning-off-auto-updates

All options have pro's and con's. Sometimes the browser is updated before the new driver is released and packaged in the WebDriverManager packages. Disabling auto updates means you might need to upgrade by hand. Still having control over your version might help with the stability if your delivery pipeline.

My order of options would be 3. 2. 4. 1.

Comment: Really 3 is just a way to achieve 2 and 4 just a way to achieve 1!

Comment: @jonrsharpe Maybe they are extentions, but I think the original poster did not consider automating the actions. The options are actionable, and yes overlap.

Comment: Many Thanks @NielsvanReijmersdal

Answer (score 1):

Its interesting to know that many are facing this mindset issue ( Not technical):

> Here you are asking whether you should update driver or downgrade
> browser

**This shows below issues in your testing process:**

1. This clearly shows that you didn't had risk analysis on what test
   environment to set up
2. You are not sure which version of browser your customers uses
3. Do we still need to support older version
4. Do we need to support all the new versions of a browser
5. Which all browser, os and their versions need to be tested on

**So answer to your question is**

it depends on your risk analysis on what will be the effect if you don't test on latest version and what will be the effect  if not tested in the version that you had in your system.

Make the decision accordingly not according to what makes the test passes.

Product can work in one version and sometimes break in another , so don't take it for granted that if it passes in latest then it will on older.

so understand your **Userbase when designing test strategy**

Comment: This is for a personal project.. But, I will keep the points you mentioned in mind, going forward.. Many Thanks..